# CSS: Padding on the sides for multiline link background?

Tags: css, hyperlink, background-color, multiline

I am trying to build links that look like these:

[image]

This from another post on here is the closest I have found - http://jsbin.com/ahoyug/1/edit

but due to using border-left the gaps between the line height is filled. As shown here:

[image]

Is this possible to do using CSS or will a JS solution be needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you want?

#### Demo

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd4UR/)

#### HTML

```
<div>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</span>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: #C9D77D;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

span {
    padding: 6px 0;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 2.2;
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 #FFF, 10px 0px 0 #FFF;
}
```

Edit: I added the `box-shadow` property from @Jaik's answer because it was totally great.

Comment: No it needs padding on the left and right of each line, but thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

It can certainly be done with CSS3 `box-shadow` easily enough. I've put up a JS Bin example here: http://jsbin.com/ahoyug/12/edit

You'll need to sort out vendor prefixes and old IE fallbacks for production.